# How to append an item in a list for use later in a If-statement

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement, pygame, append

I am creating a text-based game, and I have a problem when I try to add a Knife to pass to the Forest. My idea is that the gamer, need to use the `'C'` option to add a `Knife` to the inventory. And use that `Knife` to pass to the forest in `'B'` option. Any solution please?

```py
a1 = input('What you want to do? \nCheck some rock around you(A) \nGo to the Forest(B) \nSee around of the beach in the island(C) \n\n')
obj = []
def addknife():
    obj.append('Knife')
if a1.capitalize() == 'A':
    print()
    print('It is nothing else than a rock.')
elif a1.capitalize() == 'C':
    print()
    print('Walking for the beach, you encountered a Knife.')
    addknife()
    print(obj)
elif a1.capitalize() == 'B':
    if 'Knife' in obj:
        print('You can go to the forest.')
    else:
        print('The plants do not allow you to pass.')
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what your specific issue is, I'm guessing you need some kind of looping logic to force the player to stay in that area until they explore to find the knife, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, sorry for my bad explication, English isn't my native language hehe.
Is that correct, I need that player stay in the area until he get the Knife, and use it for cross to the Forest and continue the story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach to this is to make a data structure to hold all the game locations, and then maintain a player position which is some kind of index into this structure.  I'm trying to keep this answer *really* simple, so I'm leaving out more complex details that perhaps might make this more efficient.

Maybe start with just a list of locations, and an integer index into that list:

```
#             index 0                   index 1         index 2               index 3
locations = [ "Rocky End of The Beach", "On The Beach", "Edge of The Forest", "In The Forest" ]
player_location = 0
```

So at the start, the player can be shown `locations[ player_location ]`, which would be "Rocky End of The Beach".

Similarly to `locations`, maybe there could be a list of objects which lay at each location:

```
objects = [ [ ], [ "Knife" ], [ "Coconut", "Banana" ], [ ] ]
```

Obviously we have a list of lists, so if the `player_location` was `2`, the available objects would be `[ "Coconuts", "Bananas" ]`

So to show the description of the location to the player, it is now a combination of location and objects:

```
def showLocation( player_location ):
    global locations, objects
    # show the location description
    print( locations[ player_location ], end='. ' )
    # show the location's objects
    if ( len( objects[ player_location ] ) > 0 ):
        print( "There is: " )
        for item in objects[ player_location ]:
            print( item, end=", " )
    print("") # end-of-line
```

So at the "beach" position (`player_location` is `1`), this location-text would become:

> On The Beach. There is: Knife

Yet another list of exits could control which way the player can move from the current location, and another list to indicate which "key" is needed.  So if the player is at location `0`, they can move to `1`=beach, `2`=forest-edge.  If the player is "on the beach" they can only move back to index=0 (rocky end), etc.

```
exits = [ [ 1, 2 ], [ 0 ], [ 0, 2 ], [ 1 ] ]   # numbers of joined locations
keys  = [ [ ], [ ], [ ], [ "Knife" ] ]         # objects needed to enter
```

The `keys` indicates which item needs to be in the player's possession before they are allowed to enter that location.  So for the first 3 locations, no object is needed.  But to enter the forest (which can only be accessed from "edge of forest"), the player needs to have "Knife".

A system of simple lists like this can define a set of rules about your locations.  then the same code can loop around asking the player for commands.  The command is compared against the location.  So, for example, "get banana" only works if the `objects` list has a "banana" item at that particular `player_location` index.

Start off with a simple set of rules-data, maybe even just the location names, and just keep adding more and more features to it.

Writing some pseudocode:

```
# Do Forever:
#     Show player the location description
#     Get input from player
#     if a movement command
#         if player has key-object to move, or no object needed
#             change the `player_location` index
#         else
#             Show "You need object XXX" to player
#     if a get/drop command and item valid
#         change the player & location objects list
```

Comment: THANKS YOU SO MUCH!
Already it's been late in Argentina, so tomorrow I'll try this.
I'm new with this and your solution really helps me to improve!

Comment: Glad I could help.  When I first started programming I wrote text adventures :D